# Index list regardless of Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's say I have a list of size 3

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and my user gives the index position of 4.  It would error with index out of range. Which in most cases that is a good thing, but what I need is a was to say regardless of the list size (assuming `len > 0`), it returns a values.

So in the example above, then value would be 'b'.

```
'a' = 0
'b' = 1
'c' = 2
'a' = 3
'b' = 4
```

Same with values in reverse, if I give -4.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: So, `index % len(a)`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that would work for positive, but for -4 it would return 'c' instead.  Though I would argue that's what it's supposed to be instead of what OP expects.

Comment: @Idlehands What should it return, for OP?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I think I misunderstood OP.  I read "same value in reverse, if I give -4" (in which case, 'b').  But I think they just meant same logic for reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Coldspeed pointed out the modulo operator is the right tool for that, it gives you the rest of the integer division - if you use

```
number % len(list)
```

it will only give you indexes that are valid. 0 if it divides w/o rest or up to len(list)-1 - exactly matching the indexes available on your list.

For

```
data = ['a','b','c']

for n in range(-5,6):
    print(n, '-->', data[n % len(data)])
```

Output:

```
-4 --> c
-3 --> a
-2 --> b
-1 --> c
0 --> a
1 --> b
2 --> c
3 --> a
4 --> b
5 --> c
```

and so on.